# Browser vuex store data have but when I retrieve data from vuex it show me empty every array

Tags: vue.js, vuex

here my vuex browser store
[image]

here my component store
[image]

In this situation how can I solve it?

Comment: The question doesn't contain enough information. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. You shouldn't use console for debugging the way you do it. It doesn't reflect the actual state of things

Comment: please add some code of when you are mutating the data and printing it. it may be a reactivity problem